# How do I restore applications in taskbar after killing explorer and desktop through “Alt+F4” and then Ctrl-Alt-Shift cancel?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

In Windows 7, after bringing up the shutdown dialog by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on desktop, the whole desktop stuffs can be killed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking the Cancel button.

Now, after I start a new task of Explorer, the Chrome icon on the taskbar no longer appear as running, and when I start a new instance of Chrome the old tabs did not appear. However the old Chrome instance is actually running in the background. Is there any way for it to restore?

Comment: Why are you killing the explorer and desktop? In any case the answer is to log off and log on again.